# sql query join two tables on one table column equals to some columns in another table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

Customers phones : contains first name, last name and phone:
[phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QXFj.png)

Customers Email: contains full name (first name + last name) and email.
[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gexj.png)

I have to join them in order to get this result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNnvp.png)

My query:

```
select *, email 
from customersPhones 
join customersEmail on ??
```

How can I do it?

Comment: [ask] [mre] [text/code before links/images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [help]

Answer (score 0):

This will work for MySQL, similar solutions will work for other SQL variants

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, email
FROM phones
JOIN email ON
email.name = CONCAT(phones.firstname, ' ', phones.lastname)
```